# Extract index(row) from a textbox in a gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox

Hi i want to extract index (Rows) from a grid view and i use a text box in it. the id should extract from text box in gridview. I use this code:

```
protected void TextBox_Email_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    TextBox thisTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)thisTextBox.Parent.Parent;
    int rowindex = 0;
    int idx = currentRow.RowIndex;

    string ArticleID = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[idx].Values[1];
}
```

But the VS gave me this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.
```

Can any body helps me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent of the `DataControlFieldCell` will be the `GridViewRow`:

```
protected void TextBox_Email_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox thisTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)thisTextBox.Parent.Parent.Parent;
    int rowindex = 0;
    int idx = currentRow.RowIndex;

    string ArticleID = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[idx].Values[1];
}
```